# Adyen Web SDK How to log product information?

Tags: adyen

So I'm currently using the Adyen Web SDK in conjunction with NodeJS, and was hoping to get some help with something.

Basically I'm building a store that sells digital products, and when users purchase a product, I store that information in my database. However, I'd also like to somehow store it with Adyen so that I can see in the list of transactions in the Adyen control panel what product was purchased for each transaction. (Without manually checking my Database since ideally it would be nice to export this in the reports as well!)

I've dug through the API docs for Adyen but nothing seems to be referenced about doing anything like this other than `lineItems` (https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/v41/paymentSession)

But `lineItems` seems more for physical businesses I think? + I'm not sure if this information is even viewable in the Adyen Control Panel.

If this isn't possible, then what's the best option? Export the transactions from Adyen and loop through my database and grab the information for each transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using metadata. It is an available field in [/paymentSession](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/v41/paymentSession) (and most of adyen's API calls). It's a hashmap you can put up to 20 key/value pairs.

You can then have the reports return the metadata in a new column. The metadata will be added as a JSON string. Though you have to reach out to adyen's support to enable returning metadata in reports.